# Removing padding from toggle button in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, togglebutton

I am creating a simple toggle button in android and setting background as a drawable.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/tag_text"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"/>
```

toggle_selector.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

toggle_button_off and toggle_button_on have simple shape drawable with some color.

And this is how I am inflating this toggle button into my view:

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tags, null);
        ToggleButton tag = ((ToggleButton)child.findViewById(R.id.tag_text));
        tag.setText("Testing");
        tag.setTextOff("Testing");
        tag.setTextOn("Testing");
        flowlayout.addView(child);
```

The problem is there is just too much padding around the text in toggle button and I am not able to get rid of it by setting `padding = "0dp"`. Text on these buttons are dynamically added so setting a constant height weight is not helping too.

[image]

Comment: what You mean with too much padding? What about change the text size?

Comment: padding between text and the boundary of togglebutton. I want the button to wrap the text.

Comment: that is default height and width if you wanna wrap then you have to make drawables of image or give height or width

Comment: Make sure there is no padding in toggle_button_off and toggle_button_on

Comment: there is no padding in toggle_button_off and toggle_button_on. just the color

Comment: instead of width and height as wrap content, give your own dp values.

Comment: But the text on toggle button is dynamic. how do I handle that?

Comment: like Vishnu said, I think it is the only solution to give fixed sizes to the button..

Comment: dynamic?  You mean You set the text size programmatically?

Comment: can you specify what do you mean by dynamic, is it other than on/off.

Comment: No I am writing text on toggle button dynamically while creating it. I have added that code in question. check it out

Comment: set android:minWidth and android:minHeight to your toggle button. The button will automatically increase with if the width of the text is long.

Comment: I have set the min width height to 0dp and wrapped the width and height. And this seem to work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I got the solution by setting minWidth, minHeight to 0dp. Wrapping content in the width and height. And then adding the custom padding to togglebutton that I want.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/tag_text"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"/>
```

Comment: Does not work for me, unfortunately. I have programatically set those values and the ToggleButton still adds that large padding. Android 5.0.1

Comment: The only way I found to remove padding is to set programmatically the minHeight AND the minimumHeight to 0 (you can't set the minimumHeight into the xml layout) : 
toggleButton.setMinHeight(0);
toggleButton.setMinimumHeight(0);
Idem for the width

Answer (score 1):

Use CheckedTextView instead:

```
 final CheckedTextView toggle = new CheckedTextView(clipboardWordsLayout.getContext());
 toggle.setText(kanji);
 final int min = Views.dp2px(48, clipboardWordsLayout.getContext());
 toggle.setMinimumWidth(min);
 toggle.setMinimumHeight(min);
 toggle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
 toggle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.togglebutton);
 toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         toggle.setChecked(!toggle.isChecked());
     }
 });
```