# Cannot change the width of a button below a certain minimum

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

I have this code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToggleButtonSize extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        var toggleButton = new ToggleButton();
        toggleButton.setMaxHeight(10);
        toggleButton.setMaxWidth(10);
        // tried also
        toggleButton.setStyle("-fx-max-width: 10; -fx-pref-width: 10;");

        var pane = new FlowPane(toggleButton);

        var scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but when I use MobileApplication instead the minimum width does not go to 10:

[image]

How can I shrink the size like when using Application?

Comment: I think that text inside your `ToggleButton` limits height to its font size ; even if you don't want to add text, JavaFX defines an empty text for buttons. Try to define  `toggleButton.setStyle("-fx-max-width: 10; -fx-pref-width: 10; -fx-font-size: 1;");` and tell me if there is a result.

Comment: Hello, you're having problems with the default padding/margin/spacing on the mobile view, you'll have to change its defaults to ignore this. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410227/android-toggle-button-custom-size-padding-spacing?rq=1

Comment: @0009laH That doesn't work and it shouldn't matter what the text size is if it's an empty string.

Comment: @res I don't see how that helps, that question is about he android api, not javafx and gluon mobile. Perhaps you want to write an answer that works for the code I posted.

Comment: @Mark I am really surprised, because it works for me.
NB: **JavaFX buttons have text when they are created**; even if you see nothing on your screen, your `ToggleButton` instance sets the text property with value `""`, so font size has an influence. Add `System.out.println("[" + toggleButton.getText() + "]");` before the `// tried also` and you will see

Comment: If you are using Gluon Mobile (when you extend `MobileApplication`) there is also a css applied that sets a minimum width/height to the toggle button. As a solution try to set it to 0.

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes, setting the min width as well in the css works, thanks!

Comment: @0009laH I think you are not using `MobileApplicaion`. If you are then post an answer with code that works. With just javafx it works fine as it is without changing the font. The empty string doesn't matter because the size calculation doesn't take it into account.